# Cassandra: - Newly added node not visible in nodetool status

Tags: cassandra

I have a single node Cassandra cluster and I added a new node to that cluster. I made sure that the cluster name is same as well as the rack-dc properties are same. I also made sure that the nodes can communicate through all necessary ports. I can cqlsh from both nodes to each other as well as telnet all required ports 7000,7199,9042

cassandra.yaml for new node

```
1) seed: - "<old_node_ip>,<new_node_ip>"
2) auto_bootstrap: - true
3) listen_address: <new_node_ip>
4) rpc_address: <new_node_ip>
```

nodetool status command shows only the host node(itself) on both nodes

Running cassandra v 3.11.4 on both with open jdk 8

Am I missing anything?

### Update

Here's the log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any peers
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1435) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:566) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:823) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:683) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:632) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:388) [apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:620) [apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:732) [apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2019-10-21 13:08:14,218 HintsService.java:209 - Paused hints dispatch
WARN  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2019-10-21 13:08:14,219 Gossiper.java:1559 - No local state, state is in silent shutdown, or node hasn't joined, not announcing shutdown
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2019-10-21 13:08:14,219 MessagingService.java:981 - Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
INFO  [ACCEPT-/10.128.1.3] 2019-10-21 13:08:14,220 MessagingService.java:1336 - MessagingService has terminated the accept() thread
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2019-10-21 13:08:14,764 HintsService.java:209 - Paused hints dispatch
```

it says unable to gossip with peers but I can telnet on JMX port and the seed values are mentioned correct as well

Comment: Does the `cluster_name` match on both nodes?  Also, what does the log say about handshaking with the first node?

Comment: As @Aaron suggested, the log will tell you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Yes the cluster_name is same , i double checked that

Comment: Hmm.  Are you using node-to-node SSL?  Because that'll be on 7001, and will require matching truststores.  Or it could be a case of internal vs. external IP addresses.  Either way, your nodes can't gossip with each other, so there's something not quite right along the way.

Comment: Actually there is no SSL for internode communication, I haven't enabled it. One thing is on my old_node the cassandra is using localhost (127.0.0.1) as shown in nodetool status. Does it has to do with anything with this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three main things required for getting a new node to join/gossip with an existing node:

1. `cluster_name` - The cluster names of the two nodes *must* match exactly (case-sensitive).
2. `seeds` - The new node must use the existing node as a seed node.  If you're working in a cloud environment, the "external" (aka "floating") IP addresses must be used.
3. node-to-node SSL (*if used*) - The nodes must have matching truststores to connect.

> One thing is on my old_node the cassandra is using localhost (127.0.0.1) as shown in nodetool status.

2a. Neither of the nodes can use the home IP of 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Thanks, I figured... The host was using 127.0.0.1 which was causing all kinds of problems. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when trying to add a new node to a single DC cluster. The reason behind my error was that my **broadcast_address** parameter in cassandra.yaml had a different IP than the listen_address. I set it to blank and restarted the server which fixed the issue.

```
# Address to broadcast to other Cassandra nodes
# Leaving this blank will set it to the same value as listen_address
broadcast_address:
```